# Best way to process lots of POJOs

Tags: java

I have an ever growing data set ( stored in a google spreadsheet from day one  ) which I now want to do some analysis on.  I have some basic spread sheet processing done which worked fine when the data set was < 10,000 but now that I have over 30,000 rows it takes a painful length of time to refresh the sheet when I make any changes.

So basically each data entry contains the following fields (among other things):

```
Name, time, score, initial value, final value
```

My spreadsheet was ok as a data analysis solution for stuff like giving me all rows where Name contained string "abc" and score was < 100.

However,  as the number of rows increases it takes google sheets longer and longer to generate a result.

So I want to load all my data into a Java program ( Java because this is the language I am most familiar with and want to use this as a meaningful way to refresh my java skills also. )

I also have an input variable which my spread sheet uses when processing the data which I adjust in incremental steps to see how the output is affected. But to get a result for each incremental change to this input variable takes far too long.  This is something I want to automate so I can set the range of the input value, increment step and then have the system generate the output for each incremental value.

My question is, what is the best way to load this data into a java program.  I have the data in a txt file so figured I could read each line into its own pojo and when all 30,000 rows are loaded into an ArrayList start crunching through this. Is there a more efficient data container or method I could be using?

Comment: Please spend some time formatting your text correctly. It is really hard to read a huge chunk of unformatted text. Also make sure to tag your question good. Otherwise the experts will not find your question and nobody will be able to answer it.

Comment: It sound like you need a database.

Comment: It sounds like a typical instance of the X-Y problem (http://xyproblem.info/). You waste energy asking how to load data into a Java program, whilst your real problem is how to store and process data in general. Yes, @StephenC is absolutely right - you need a database.

Comment: Don't know, @MayoMan, you're getting the X-Y sell here. Do you think now, you want a database? "...when all 30,000 rows are loaded ... start crunching through this" doesn't sound like a storage problem. Do you think sql (plsql?) would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of arbitrary (unspecified, probably ad-hoc) data processing to do, and using a spread-sheet is proving too slow, you would be better off looking for a better tool or more applicable language.

Here are some of the many possibilities:

- Load the data into an SQL database and perform your analysis using SQL queries.  There are many interactive database tools out there.
- OpenRefine.  Never used it, but I am told it is powerful and easy to use.
- Learn Python or R and their associated data analysis libraries.

---

It would be possible to implement this all in Java and make it go *really fast*, but for a dataset of 30,000 records it is (IMO) not worth the development effort.